# Docker run not working with: failed to load ... permission denied

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile, containers, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy on Digital Ocean (which is a Datacenter), I'm having a problem which prevent the deployment.

The build process works good.

My project Dockerfile:

```
####################################################################################################
## Builder
####################################################################################################
FROM rust:latest AS builder

RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
RUN apt update && apt install -y musl-tools musl-dev
RUN update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /myrustapp

COPY ./ .

RUN cargo build --release

RUN chmod -R 777 /myrustapp

####################################################################################################
## Final image
####################################################################################################
FROM scratch

WORKDIR /myrustapp

COPY --from=builder /myrustapp/target/release/myrustapp ./

# RUN chmod -R 777 /myrustapp <- this occure a build crash because sh is not present in scratch image
```

And at the end (the EQ command executed by D.O): `docker run myimage /myrustapp`

The result / error :

```
[myrustapp] [2022-01-19 14:14:19] starting container: starting non-root container [/myrustapp]: creating process: failed to load /myrustapp: permission denied
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what's the purpose of `/myrustapp` argument in `docker run` command?

Comment: The purpose is the run command in the container, but actually in Digital Ocean I have a field to specify the launch command in the container.
So here is just an example of the equivalent command in raw docker command @LeiYang

Comment: Depending on your version of Docker, you might try adding `--chmod=755` to your `COPY` command.

Comment: Is your Docker command running user is in docker group? I mean sudo usermod -aG docker $USER ...

Comment: @Jmb Digital Ocean shows me : "error building image: parsing dockerfile: Dockerfile parse error line 47: Unknown flag" after adding this flag, but working on my own system for the build side, running side is not working.

Comment: @TelinovDmitri the Dockerfile is pushed to Digital Ocean which is the datacenter and C.A.S, I can't manipulate the server at this level

Comment: Can you build and run the container locally? The Dockerfile in your question is 27 lines but you say that DO complains "parse error in line 47". Is this just a typo? It's curious that the log says "starting non-root container" but you don't explicitly run as a non-root user. I assume DO is starting the container as such. Would your Rust binary run correctly as non-root? Have you tried a minimal OS (perhaps a Debian slim?) instead of `scratch`?

Comment: A long time ago (Oct 2020), I wrote a basic rust HTTP server and deployed it to DO Apps. Hopefully it may help you identify a problem: https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/201008/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I made a new image of my container with MUSL builder to prevent dependencies from missing with a scratch or an alpine image.

My new Dockerfile:

```
# Build Stage
FROM ekidd/rust-musl-builder:latest AS builder
# We need to add the source code to the image because `rust-musl-builder`
# assumes a UID of 1000, but TravisCI has switched to 2000.
WORKDIR /myrustapp

ADD --chown=rust:rust . ./

RUN cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

# Bundle Stage
FROM scratch

# If you want SSL for requests
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=builder /myrustapp/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/myrustapp /myrustapp

CMD ["/myrustapp"]
```

It works perfectly, actually, but maybe it can't fit with all dependencies.

If this happens, the solution of [@DazWilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin) works good, but the image will be much heavier.

I just needed to edit it a few to make it works (2022).

The edited version:

```
FROM rust:latest as builder

RUN USER=root cargo new --bin myrustapp

WORKDIR /myrustapp

COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.toml
RUN cargo build --release
RUN rm src/*.rs

ADD . ./

RUN rm ./target/release/deps/myrustapp*

RUN cargo build --release


FROM debian:latest as runtime

WORKDIR /bin

# Copy from builder and rename to 'server'
COPY --from=builder /myrustapp/target/release/myrustapp ./server

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV TZ=Etc/UTC \
    USER=appuser

RUN groupadd ${USER} \
    && useradd -g ${USER} ${USER} && \
    chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /bin

USER ${USER}

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["./server"]
```

Thanks everyone for the help!